# bootstrap dropdown menu and error with $_GET

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a single page site with twitter bootstrap scrolling,
taken from this example: http://brocknunn.com/untame/scroller/.
It works but I have a strange problem. From a dropdown menu should pass variables via GET but does not work,   in the address bar does not appear any var (for example index.php?id = 1).... It only works when I disable the code at bottom of the page

```
<script>
              $ ('# top-nav'). onePageNav ({
                  currentClass: 'active',
                  changeHash: true,
                  scrollSpeed​​: 1200
             });
         </ script>
```

The dropdown menu is a standard bootstrap 2.3.2

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="top-nav">
                        <li ><a href="#section-0">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-1">Page1</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Foto Gallery<span class="caret red-caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php?id=1#section-2">Gallery 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?id=2#section-2">Gallery 2</a></li>
                    </ul>                    
                        </li> 
                        <li><a href="#section-3">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, and I am pretty sure that, the jQuery plugin prevents the default GET action associated with `<a href` links.

It just fetches the hashtag fragment `#section-2` and scrolls down to an anchor that matches the fragment.

Try using a different plugin or not using a plugin at all, scrolling actions are very simple to implement.

See the code from the plugin http://brocknunn.com/untame/scroller/js/plugins.js:

```
                onAfter: function() {
                    //Do we need to change the hash?
                    if(self.config.changeHash) {
                        window.location.hash = newLoc;
                    }

                    //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                    self.bindInterval();

                    //End callback
                    if(self.config.end) {
                        self.config.end();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

**The plugin is not able to follow your links.**

Comment: ok thanks. Can you tell me a plugin for a smooth scroll easy to install and that does not create this kind of problems?

Comment: I don't use plugins for such simple tasks. You can look at the sourcecode from your plugin and just copy their code until the default preventing part.

Comment: You have a logical error anyways. On firing a GET request, the page changes/reloads. Why do you wonna scroll and reload at the same time? Use either the one or the other method of navigation or trigger an ajax request.